# Angular template containing boolean condition not updating on state change?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, echarts

I'm trying to update a template when a pie chart slice is clicked.

This is the template.

```
    <h1>{{slice && slice.name}}</h1>
    <h1>{{slice && slice.value}}</h1>
```

Here's a demo.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-p8bxjx?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fecharts.component.ts

When one of the pie chart segments is clicked it emits an object containing the `name` and `value` of the segment that was clicked.

The `main` component receives this via the listener `onPieSelect` and sets the `slice` property on the `main` component like this:

```
  onPieSelect(e: any) {
    console.log('slice clicked', e);
    this.slice = e;
  }
```

We can see that the object is being received via the log, however the template is not being updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

echarts spawn events outside of angular, and thus, char events don't trigger change detection.

to fix that wrap the handler into an ngzone run

```
 ngZone = inject(NgZone);
 ...
 onChartInit(echarts: any) {
    let self = this;
    this.echartsIntance = echarts;
    this.echartsIntance.on('click',  (event: any) => {
      this.ngZone.run(() => {
    // Print name in console
        console.log('Event Name', event.name);
        console.log('Event Value', event.value);
        console.log('Event Value', event.color.colorStops[0].color);
        const pieData: any = { name: event.name, value: event.value };
        self.onPieSliceSelect.emit(pieData);
      })
      
    });
  }
```

Comment: you can also use a `(charClick)` event handler on a template. this way angular wrapper ngx-echarts would handle the ngZone for you